# php error_reporting- disabling then enabling with 0 and 1 respectively does not work

Tags: php, error-handling

PHP snippet:

```
 <?php
error_reporting(0);
$a;

echo ' a = '.$a.'<br>';



error_reporting(1);

echo ' b= '.$b;

?>
```

and the ouput is

```
a =
b=
```

without any notice.

I expected the     `error_reporting(1)` to work to show errors. But if I use     `error_reporting(E_ALL)` instead, it shows the notice for the undefined variable `b`;

Questions are :

1) If the parameter  is  0 or `false` then errors are supressed, then why not 1 or `true` will work in the reverse way ?

2) Where is it mentioned in the documentation of [PHP site](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) that 0 or `false` can be passed as  a parameter whereas I can find [here](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php) that `E_ALL` can be used as a parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

[`error_reporting()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) expects [a bit field parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) `$level` which represents the various [error_reporting options](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php). To enable notices about undefined variables you want the combination of `E_ALL` and `E_STRICT`:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

(From PHP 5.4 you can omit `E_STRICT` since it is included in `E_ALL`). Using the integer `0` just means that you have disabled all options.

Depending on your ini settings you may also want to enable the displaying of errors - for debugging, disable it on production:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

**Example:**

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 

error_reporting(0);
echo $a; 

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
echo $b;
```

The example above will display a notice when you attempt to access $b which is undefined.

Comment: Just cannot find the ansewr to the 2 questions I mentioned in OP.

Comment: Just follow the links I provided. I also explained why you can pass 0. If you pass `false`, PHP will just automatically cast the value to `0`.

Comment: I followed those before. I do not find the answer why `error_reporting(1)` won't work and where in the php DOC site `0` or `false` is mentioned as the parameter.

Comment: Do you know what is a bit field?

Comment: let me understand the term.

Comment: I need more clarification . A bit field presents a bit. Is that okay ? still cannot find the answer to the 2 questions.

Comment: try to google the bit field term. you need to understand that. its they key to the answer of your questions

Answer (score 0):

`error_reporting(1)` is equivelant for `error_reporting(E_ERROR)` that means you will only activate error reporting from PHP
In your case you have to write `error_reporting(E_NOTICE)` to see the message from PHP
You can combine with many type of report `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE)`
To re activate all type of errors and warning you can write `error_reporting(-1)`
Hope  it helps

Comment: I mentioned two questions namely 1 and 2 and cannot understand the answer to those.